# Evaluate the integral using ln|u|

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the integral. (Remember to use ln |u| where appropriate. Use C for the constant of integration.)

$(7x^2 + 2x − 7)/(x^3 − x)$

I don't get how to use ln|u|. I have a ton of these questions and I can't do a single one. Can someone show me this is an example? thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** Rewrite $\dfrac{7x^2+2x-7}{x^3-x}$ in the form $\dfrac{A}{x}+\dfrac{B}{x+1}+\dfrac{C}{x-1}$ and integrate those easier functions. This is done using [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).

---

As an example of partial fraction decomposition, consider the expression $\dfrac{5x^2+2x-9}{x^3-x^2-6x}$. Factoring the denominator we get $x^3-x^2-6x = x(x-3)(x+2)$. So we want to try and rewrite $\dfrac{5x^2+2x-9}{x^3-x^2-6x}$ as $\dfrac{A}{x}+\dfrac{B}{x-3}+\dfrac{C}{x+2}$ where $A,B,C$ are constants to be determined. So we get

$\dfrac{5x^2+2x-9}{x^3-x^2-6x} = \dfrac{A}{x}+\dfrac{B}{x-3}+\dfrac{C}{x+2} \\
\Longrightarrow 5x^2+2x-9=A(x-3)(x+2)+Bx(x+2) +Cx(x-3) \\
\Longrightarrow 5x^2+2x-9= Ax^2-Ax-6Ax +Bx^2+2Bx +Cx^2-3Cx \\
\Longrightarrow 5 = A+B+C\\
\phantom{\Longrightarrow\ } 2 = -A+2B-3C \\
\phantom{\Longrightarrow\ } -9 = -6A$

Solving this system gives $A = \frac{3}{2}$, $B = \frac{14}{5}$ and $C = \frac{7}{10}$. So the original expression can be written as $\dfrac{3}{2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{x} + \dfrac{14}{5}\cdot\dfrac{1}{x-3}+\dfrac{7}{10}\cdot\dfrac{1}{x+2}$.